# How can I speed the R process for determining multicollineariy in 22 bioclimatic variables?

Tags: r

I have 22 predictors in rasters, which I want to use in species distribution modelling. Using R, I have stacked them. Now I am trying to determine multicollinearity amongst them to screen the variables. But the code is taking too long and am not sure when it would return with the result. I have the following code:

```
k <- layerStats(p, 'pearson', na.rm=T) ## "p" is the raster stack.
```

How can I speed up the process? After the above step, I want to do correlation matrix and variance inflation factor.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not if this is what you want, you should do it first with a small sample. Based on your description, this is not what you want.
You could do (using a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example):

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster") )
s <- stack(r, 1/r, sqrt(r))
pairs(s)
```

Or for more formal analysis:

```
set.seed(321)
x  <- sampleRegular(s, 10000)
cor(x, use="complete.obs")
#           test.1     test.2      layer
#test.1  1.0000000 -0.8505059  0.9886518
#test.2 -0.8505059  1.0000000 -0.9155957
#layer   0.9886518 -0.9155957  1.0000000
```

Comment: Prof. thank you so much! I am just a beginner of R user and finding it difficult. I hope you don't mind me saying that I still couldn't make out your code above. I have all my rasters saved in my external hard drive. How could I use your code for multiples raster files to access from my external hard drive and stack them? Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

To easily calculate the VIF, there's also the `vif()` function from package **usdm**: https://github.com/babaknaimi/usdm.